Given a vector field in spherical coordinates, compute the flux through a disk at z = -d
I want to compute the flux of the magnetic field $B = \frac{\mu_0m}{4\pi r^3}(2cos(\theta)\vec{e_r}+sin(\theta)\vec{e_\theta})$ through the disk at $z=-d$ with radius b centered around the z-axis. Parameterising the plane in cylindrical coordinates seems easiest, and I end up with a surface normal $\vec{n} = (0,0,-r)$. Now, how do I convert the vector field to be able to take the dot-product and integrate? I technically know the coordinate conversions but I can't seem to wrap my head around expressing spherical $\vec{e_r}$ and $\vec{e_\theta}$ in cylindrical coordinates. I'm sure there's a transformation matrix but I couldn't find it. Could somebody help me out please? I'm also happily taking suggestions in case cylindrical coordinates are not in fact the easiest way.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates
